# Listener en Laravel Test

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, test, phpunit

Estoy utilizando tests de Laravel 8 y deseo emitir una alerta, ya sea vía email o enviando algún mensaje a Slack; sin embargo no encuentro en la documentación una manera de tener un listener para estos eventos.

Un ejemplo de los tests que ejecuto es el siguiente

```
/** @test */
public function savePost()
{
    $token = $this->getToken();
    $response = $this->get("/api/post/link?link={$this->post}&api_token={$token}");
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Comment: No entiendo bien a qué te refieres... Teniendo creado el evento... ¿Probaste despacharlo en el test? `MiEvento::dispatch();`. ¿O es un evento que se debería despacha al llamar a ese endpoint de la api, y lo que quieres es comprobar que eso suceda?

Comment: Lo que necesito es que al llamar a esa ruta pueda comprobar los parámetros de respuesta y si llega a fallar mande una notificación; con la notificación no tengo problema, solo al querer "escuchar" cuando el test falle